# python class with simulated items()

Tags: python, class, items

Here's is my simple class:

```
 class row(object):
        __slots__ = ("tan_id", "proc_name")
        def __init__(
            self, 
            tan_id = "INDETERMINATE", 
            proc_name = "INDETERMINATE"
        ):
            self.tan_id = tan_id
            self.proc_name = proc_name
```

This class used to be a dictionary, but I ran into serious memory issues. Later on in my code I use a generalized function to loop like this:

```
 for key, val in row.items()
```

I don't want to change that... so my question is, how do I simulate that item() function in the class so that it works seamlessly in the existing for loop.

Comment: What were the `items` before for the row example you are showing?

Comment: row={"tan_id": tan_id, "proc_name": proc_name}

Comment: @gunslingor sounds like you should have been using a `namedtuple`.

Comment: I agree, except it really needs to be muteable... so slots was the answer. Memory issues are forcing this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply implement an `items` method that mimicks the previous `dict.items()` behaviour by producing the same key-value pairs:

```
class row(object):
    # ...
    def items(self):
        # this is the iterator behaviour of 'items' (Py3) or 'iteritems' (Py2)
        yield 'tan_id', self.tan_id
        yield 'proc_name', self.proc_name
        # for the Py2 items behaviour, put these pairs into a list 
        # and return the list

    # Or, more generally:
    def items(self):
        for slot in self.__slots__:
            yield slot, getattr(self, slot)
```

Comment: The second option is ideal if it works (testing... it should), because I have 20 classes similarly structures but most have 20-50 variables defined. Thanks.